# How frequently are offers rescinded after signing

Tags: contracts, visa

After the signing of the offer letter from both sides, a starting date was decided and accepted by me. Due to maybe an over optimistic forecasting on their side, the working visa was not ready for the agreed upon date and so the starting date was pushed back (the precise day is still under discussion).

How frequently/possible is it for a large company to rip the contract at this point ?

Comment: I don't have statistics, but I believe the answer is "rarely after you have the job offer in writing; less rarely if all you have is a verbal promise." Don't quit your current job before you have the new one on paper, if you can avoid it.

Comment: As I mentioned that the offer has been signed by both party, I thought it would be clear that everything is on paper. The question targets that especially, it is known that verbal offer tends to be prone to rescinding, how about written offer, after signature.

Comment: I wouldn't be unduly worried at this stage. It's now a formal offer. Hiring managers in my experience are often keener to get you on board than the red tape allows. Almost every job I have started has started late for this reason and I didn't even need a visa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities for delay with your visa, but most companies would not rescind an offer unless they have strong reasons like your background check did not go well. Even then they would ask you for reasons or get back to you. Otherwise you should be good.Good luck.